# setEnabled not working on some devices in Android

Tags: java, android, button

I have a button on my screen that is dynamically enabled or disabled when user make a few actions. Here is the code that changes button status:

```
    private void setContinueButtonStatus() {
        boolean status = false;

        // Every time user selects a ticket this is increased
        for (TicketSpecification specification : ticketSpecificationList.specifications) {
            if (specification.getMyCount() > 0) {
                status = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        findViewById(R.id.btnContinue).setEnabled(status);
    }
```

My button xml is:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnContinue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="@string/continue_button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

My problem is that this code works fine in Moto G5S, making button enabled or not after user interaction.

But on Galaxy S9 and Android Emulator (I'm using Pixel XL) button keeps disabled, even after user click. But, if I click on button it become enabled and performs the click normally.

Anyone knows if this is a bug on Android, or am I making something wrong?

Comment: Did you try `focusable="false"` attribute in Button xml?

Comment: Yeah, I´ve tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve found the bug here.

I was using an external lib to manage some stuff on my app, and this lib was returning the info needed to update button on a thread that wasn't main thread.

I´ve fixed the problem by redirecting my code to main thread.